# Django serializer error expected number but got [28]

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django and Python, I'm using Django-rest-framework for building RESTfull API.
I have a view like this

```
class ProfileViewSet(APIView):

# to find if isAuthenticate then
authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

 def post(self, request):
    user_id = request.data['user_id']
    request.data.pop('user_id')
    request.data['user_id'] = int(user_id)
    serializer = ProfileSerializer(
        context={'request': request}, data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.create(validated_data=request.data)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors)
```

and my serializer goes something like this

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # id = serializers.IntegerField(source='profile.id')
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='user.id')
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    profile = Profile
    # depth=2

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'image', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                  'description', 'mobile', 'current_location', 'user_id')
        read_only_fields = ('user', 'user_id')
```

from my frontend, I'm sending user_id as a string so I'm parsing it to number.

error:- `TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got [28].`

JSON from request.data:- `'user_id':'28'
'first_name':'sdsd'
'last_name':'dsd'
'mobile':'2323323'
'current_location':'23233'
 description':'23'`

Comment: how does your json from request look like

Comment: my request.data looks like:- 
 'user_id':'28'
'first_name':'sdsd'
'last_name':'dsd'
'mobile':'2323323'
'current_location':'23233'
 description':'23'

where user_id is a string

Answer (score 0):

in `JSON`, '28' is different from 28 just like a programming language, cause '28' is a string, not a number

Comment: Yes, that's why I parsed int. like ```request.data['user_id'] = int(user_id)```